# For each not showing correctly empty array

Tags: swift, xcode

First of all, this is my first swift project so there may be some silly errors I haven't realized about. I'm developing a to do app for iOS. The problem I came across is that when displaying an empty array with a for each it should show some horizontal lines but it don't show anything.

Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var newTodo = "";
    @State private var allTodos: [TodoItem] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                List{
                    ForEach(allTodos){
                        todoItem in Text(todoItem.todo)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
struct TodoItem: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let todo: String
}
```

Here is the image of the horizontal lines
[image]

Comment: What horizontal lines, it’s hard to understand what you mean? Should they only be there when the array is empty?

Comment: I have modified the question and added an image of how it should be. Hope now its clearer.@JoakimDanielson

Comment: And when the array is not empty there are no lines visible?

Comment: When the array is not empty the lines are visible although the lines are not displayed in the same way that the photo above

Comment: Those "horizontal lines" are separator lines in a table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want these lines you need to add a UITableView and display the array in it.

[Here's Official Apple Documentation on Table Views.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.